# local_irq_disable does not work as expected

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

local_irq_disable()is used to disable all interrupts on the current processor

i wrote a basic code to test local_irq_disable().

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/irqflags.h>

static int __init my_init(void)
{
    pr_info("module is loaded on processor:%d\n", smp_processor_id());
    local_irq_disable();
    ssleep(10);
    local_irq_enable();
    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

When i load this on my system, it prints the following message:

[10478.930188] module is loaded on processor:5

And when i run "watch -d -n 0.2 'cat /proc/interrupts'", it still shows interrupts on those processor, what i am missing here?

Comment: You can check which interrupts are coming in this interval, if they really are. How counter in proc/interrupts is implemented? Where does it increments?

Comment: `ssleep` puts the thread into the **waiting state**. Such operation shouldn't be used in **atomic** context, and **disabling interrupts** provides exactly such context. Instead of `ssleep` you may use `mdelay`, which is busy-waiting sort of sleep. But note, that 10 seconds with disabled interrupts will be treated by the kernel as a problem: interrupts shouldn't be disabled for such long period.